# extract some part of code avoiding unmatched braces of other part

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to write JavaScript compiler where I need to deal with lot's of programming symbols so my program is bit complex then other programs. I have a incomplete pieces of code in a variable **a** in a string form , I want to extract complete property of **@style** avoiding backward unrelated symbols and convert it into pure object from incomplete object (It's actually a string). If you didn't understand please look at output example below;

I have tried it many times , But due to lack of concept to solve this kind of problem I could not solve it please help me .

```
      var a = `@style":{".time":{color:"red"}}}`;
      var b = `@style":{".time":{color:"red" , height:'10px'}}}}}}))}`;
      var b = `@style":{".time":{
                                 color:"red" , 
                                 height:'10px'
                                },
                         "@keyframes example" : {
                                    "0%" :  {background-color: 'red'},
                                    "25%" :  {background-color: 'yellow'}
                         }
                    }}}}}))}{`;
```

Expexted Output :

```
     a =  {".time":{color:"red"}}

     b =  {".time":{color:"red" , height:'10px'}}

     c =  {
          ".time":{
                   color:"red" , 
                   height:'10px'
           },
           "@keyframes example" {
               "0%" : {
                      background-color: "red"
               },
               "25%" :  {
                  background-color: "yellow"
               }
            }
      }
```

In example you can clearly see bracket **} and {** corresponding to each other is only taken but brackets which don't have corresponding opening/closing bracket are avoided.

For Clear understanding of Problem :

Let us suppose variable **a** , **b** and **c** contain complete object from where I need to extract complete property of **@style**.

Please Help Me

Comment: Why does the string have inconsistent number of `}}}))}{` at the end. Without them, you could parse the string with little modifications. Considering, you are the one creating the compiler, you have control over the data you input, yes?

Comment: There is inconsistent number of  `}}}))}{` because this pieces of code is extracted from middle of some code under certain condition , Yes I have full control over input data..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such type of problem you must use fulfillment rule  for example : Just Remember "head of coin can't be fulfilled without tail similarly boy can't be fulfilled without girl likewise compare same thing while you come to world of code **{** can't be fulfilled without **}** "

Rule : Place first thing to be fulfilled (i.e **{** ) in array and in other step when it's Opposite partner **}**  is found it's completed so place something valuable data in same place.

If you are not clear about my rule please have a look at 100% working code.

```
var out =  console.log , 
a         =  `@style":{".time":{
                             color:"red" , 
                             height:'10px'
                            },
                     "@keyframes example" : {
                                "0%" :  {background-color: 'red'},
                                "25%" :  {background-color: 'yellow'}
                     }
                }}}}}))}{`,

a          =  a.substr(a.indexOf(':')+1).replace(/\s/g,''),
state      =  [],
Endpoint   =  -1,

found      =  function(state , index){
    for(var i = 0 ; i < state.length ; i++){
      if(state[i] == '{'){
        state[i] = index;
        FirstEntry = true;
        break;
      }
    }
},

check = function(state){
   for(var j = 0 ; j < state.length ; j++){
     if(typeof state[j] !== 'number'){
       return(0);
     }
   }
  return(1);
};

for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++){
   var el = a[i];
   if(el == '{'){
     state.push(el);   
   }
   if(el == '}'){
    found(state , i);
   } 
   if(check(state)){
     Endpoint = i;
     break;
   }
}

out(Endpoint , a.substr(0,Endpoint+1));
```

Comment: Thanks for help @nirikshan Bdusal

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the keys and values cannot contain opening or closing braces you just need to ignore everything before first opening brace, then count the braces (+1 for each opening brace, -1 for each closing braces), retrieve the index of the last matching brace then ignore everything after that.

This code works for the OP test cases and the tests are demonstrated.

The code will certainly fail on edge cases which may be handled with additional replaces.
This code will definitely fail if the keys or values in your code extract contain opening or closing braces (to fix that you will have to keep track wether you are in an identifier (key) or in value and ignore inkey or invalue braces during counting).

So it will turn more and more into a heavyweight parser and won't be very efficient.

I strongly suggest that you try and use a parser generator like [PEGJS](https://pegjs.org/) instead of trying to parse yourself. Compilation itself is a hard problem, no need to add the parsing complexity...

Anyway, working example below:

```js
var a = `@style":{".time":{color:"red"}}}`;
var b = `@style":{".time":{color:"red" , height:'10px'}}}}}}))}`;
var c = `@style":{".time":{
                                 color:"red" , 
                                 height:'10px'
                                },
                         "@keyframes example" : {
                                    "0%" :  {background-color: 'red'},
                                    "25%" :  {background-color: 'yellow'}
                         }
                    }}}}}))}{`;
// Expexted Output :

test_a = {".time":{color:"red"}};

test_b = {".time":{color:"red" , height:'10px'}};

test_c = {
  ".time": {
    color:"red" , 
    height:'10px'
  },
  "@keyframes example": {
    "0%" : {
      "background-color": "red"
    },
    "25%" :  {
      "background-color": "yellow"
    }
  }
};
function parseChunk(chunk) {
  // trim everything before first brace
  var parsedChunk = chunk.replace(/^[^{]*/, '');
  // iterate over string, counting braces,
  // count++ when encountering {,
  // count -- when encountering '}',
  // break when count === 0
  var braceCount = 0;
  var matchingBraceIndex = 0;
  for(; matchingBraceIndex < parsedChunk.length; matchingBraceIndex++) {
    var c = parsedChunk.charAt(matchingBraceIndex);
    if (c === '{') {
      braceCount++;
    } else if (c === '}') {
      braceCount--;
    }
    if (braceCount === 0) break;
  };
  if (braceCount !== 0) {
    throw new Error('incomplete expression');
  }
  // trim content after last brace matching first brace
  parsedChunk = parsedChunk.substr(0, matchingBraceIndex + 1);
  // double quote identifiers
  parsedChunk = parsedChunk.replace(/(\s*|{|,)([\w-]+)(\s*:)/g, '$1"$2"$3');
  // convert single quote values to double quote values
  parsedChunk = parsedChunk.replace(/(\s*|{|,)("[\w-]+")(\s*:\s*)'((?:\\'|[^'])+)'/g, '$1$2$3"$4"');
  // the JSON should be parseable now
  try {
    return JSON.parse(parsedChunk);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error(`unparseable JSON, improve replace rules?\n$${error}`);
  }
  
}

console.log(
  parseChunk(a),
  " => ",
  JSON.stringify(parseChunk(a)) === JSON.stringify(test_a) ? 'OK' : 'NOK'
);
console.log(
  parseChunk(b),
  " => ",
  JSON.stringify(parseChunk(b)) === JSON.stringify(test_b) ? 'OK' : 'NOK'
);
console.log(
  parseChunk(c),
  " => ",
  JSON.stringify(parseChunk(c)) === JSON.stringify(test_c) ? 'OK' : 'NOK'
);
```